# Markdown libraries don't support a single \n in android

Tags: android, markdown

I tried a couple of markdown support libraries and they all seem to work except for one fact which they all have in common. They don't recognize a single \n , unless I enter \n\n. 
The libraries I have used are commonmark/ markwon/ bypass. No luck with any of them yet. 
Anyone else had a similar issue?
P.S: the text I am applying a markdown on is uneditable and returned from an API ,

```
something like "text" = __this__: __name__  \n __that__ : __name__
```

Any idea how to go about that?

Comment: AFAIK, `\n` has no meaning in Markdown. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I am trying to use it for a newline. for the text above something like __this__ :__name__ and then on the second line __that__ : __name__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A
single
newline
has
no
meaning
in
Markdown.

For example, the first sentence that I typed into this answer really looks like:

```
A
single
newline
has
no
meaning
in
Markdown.
```

A blank line (e.g., two newlines) serves as a block separator for paragraphs, etc.

Comment: so what will be the best approach to tackle this? my api text returns a single newline for 2 texts marked above , how do i make sure i can use markdown libs + get them on newlines as expected

Comment: @MarissaNicholas: Assuming that there are no other newlines in the text, use `replaceAll()` to replace one newline with two, I guess. Do that prior to Markdown processing.

Comment: Or with two trailing spaces, depending on the goal. Two newlines (one full blank line) separate paragraphs. Two trailing spaces represent a `<br>`. But doing this means your application isn't really supporting Markdown. You'll be mangling the semantics.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and found a solution.

I used the Markwon library with the following plugin, as mentioned in the [Markwon Docs](https://noties.io/Markwon/docs/v4/core/core-plugin.html#props).

> Since 4.3.0 there is a dedicated plugin to insert a new line for markdown soft breaks - SoftBreakAddsNewLinePlugin:
>
> ```
>    final Markwon markwon = Markwon.builder(this)
>         .usePlugin(SoftBreakAddsNewLinePlugin.create())
>         .build();
> ```

This works because a /n is parsed as a softbreak according to the [CommonMark Spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#soft-line-breaks).